# How to include local javascript on a Gatsby page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm a total React newbie and I guess there is something fundamental I don't quite understand here. A default Gatsby page looks like this. Is there a way to use a local .js file somewhat like this?

```
<script src="../script/script.js"></script>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have react ignore `script.js` but still have the client side use it. A default Gatsby page looks like this, is it possible to do somerthing like that there?

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}>
      <Image />
    </div>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>
  </Layout>
)
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After several hours of frustration I finally stumbled upon [discussion](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11013#issuecomment-453698163) on GitHub that solved this for me. In Gatsby, there is a thing called [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/), for which one use case is including a small script outside of the bundled code.

Anyone else in the same situation, try proceeding as follows:

1. Create a folder `static` to the root of your project.
2. Put your script `script.js` in the folder `static`.
3. Include the script in your react dom **with react-helmet**.

So in the case of the code I posted in my original question, for instance:

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { withPrefix, Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Helmet>
        <script src={withPrefix('script.js')} type="text/javascript" />
    </Helmet>
    <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}>
      <Image />
    </div>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>
  </Layout>
)
```

Notice the imports

```
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { withPrefix, Link } from "gatsby"
```

and the script element.

```
<Helmet>
    <script src={withPrefix('script.js')} type="text/javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

This would have saved hours of my time, hopefully this does it for someone else.

Comment: It worked for gatsby develop mode but not including the file correctly on gatsby build. Any suggestion please?

Comment: same here with me

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Does anyone know if it is possible to include scripts outside of the <head> tag? I often prefer having a script at the end of the body rather than right at the top for improved loading speed (or does this hardly affect anything?)

Comment: @Mayron One solution if you want a script to always load upon navigation is to load it during the componentDidMount, for example see this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13136. You can also load them at the foot of the body by using gatsby-ssr but read this also: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/

Comment: @Mayron Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066579/including-local-js-and-css-files-using-gatsbyjs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This worked fine. I wanted to include a logo from Altmetric. I tried to include the external script in html.js and using gatsby-plugin-load-script but none worked. This worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This worked great in develop AND build environments.  The only thing I added was a forward slash to '/script.js' and a defer property to make it load last.  Thx and cheers 

Answer (score 10):

**There are many ways to add scripts in GatsbyJS...**

**To execute a script on a specific page**

- create a stateless `ScriptComponent.js` file and place it inside your `/src` folder.
- in your `ScriptComponent.js` use `require()` to execute the script inside `useEffect()` like this:

  ```
  const ScriptComponent = ({
   src, // if internal,put a path relative to this component
   onScriptLoad = () => {}, // cb
   appendToHead = false,
   timeoutDuration = 10, 
   defer = false,
   isExternal = false,
  }) => {

   useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     if (isExternal) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = src;
      script.onload = onScriptLoad;

       defer
        ? script.defer = true
        : script.async = true;

       appendToHead
        ? document.head.appendChild(script)
        : document.body.appendChild(script);
      } else { // for internal scripts
       // This runs the script
       const myScript = require(src);
      }
     }, timeoutDuration);
    }, []);

   return null;
  };
  ```
- To run it on client-side, you could check the `window` object inside your `script.js` file if you didn't run it in useEffect:

  ```
   if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document) {
      // Your script here...
   }
  ```
- finally, go to the page you want to execute the script in it (e.g. `/pages/myPage.js` ), and add the component `<ScriptComponent />`

**If you want to execute a script **globally** in (every component/page) you could use the `html.js` file.**

- first, you'll have to extract the file (in case you didn't) by running:

> `cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js`

- inside your `html.js` file:

> ```
> <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{ __html:`
>   // your script here...
>   // or you could also reuse the same approach as in useEffect above
> `}} />
> ```

Comment: Would this work well with an external js? IE. The public jqueryurl?

Comment: Feels like this is the React way of doing it.

Answer (score 9):

Just create `gatsby-ssr.js` file on root folder

and add the following pattern for your scripts folder

```
import React from 'react'

export const onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <script
      key="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      defer
    />,
    <script
      key="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      defer
    />,
    <script
      key="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      defer
    />
  ])
}
```

Then, you at the end of dom you'll see the links to scripts
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use a Gatsby plugin, which to me is no different from using an external library like Helmet (plugins are npm packages after all), you could use [gatsby-plugin-load-script](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-load-script/).

You can provide either the url to the `src` attribute or a local path. If you're going to store your JS in a local file such as `some-minified-js.min.js` - make sure to store in the `static` directory at the root of your project.

Once you do this, you can access via the global object:

```
global.<object or func name here>
```

For example, I was trying to include a very small JS library via a minified file, so I stored the file in `/static/my-minified-library.min.js` and then:

1. Installed the plugin: `npm i --save gatsby-plugin-load-script`
2. Added this to my `gatsby-config.js`

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-load-script",
      options: {
        src: "/my-minified-library.min.js",
      },
    },
  ],
```

3. Accessed in my react component like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const x = new global.MyImportedLibraryObject();
}, []}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily with the Gatsby plugin ["gatsby-plugin-load-script."](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-load-script/)

Simply do this:

1. Create a folder named `static` at the root of your gatsby app
2. Place your script in it
3. Add the following configuration in `gatsby-config.js`

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-load-script',
      options: {
        src: '/test-script.js', // Change to the script filename
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby uses html.js in the src folder. Not index.html like most react projects.

Example html.js file:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default class HTML extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <html {...this.props.htmlAttributes}>
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          {this.props.headComponents}
        </head>
        <body {...this.props.bodyAttributes}>
          {this.props.preBodyComponents}
          <div
            key={`body`}
            id="___gatsby"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }}
          />
          {this.props.postBodyComponents}
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

For adding custom Javascript using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` inside `src/html.js`:

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
            var name = 'world';
            console.log('Hello ' + name);
        `,
  }}
/>
```

You can try adding your js there but, note that your js may not work as expected. You can always look into react-helmet for more dynamic apps and adding scripts to `<head>`.

Gatsby Documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if anyone still needs this answer, but here it goes:

The answer by Elliot Marques is excellent. If you need it for a local file, upload the script to Github and use a service like [JSDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/). It saves a lot of time and stress.

Answer (score 0):

React works with dynamic DOM. But for rendering it by browser, your web server should send a static index page, where React will be included as another `script` tag.

So, take a look on your `index.html` page, which you can find in `public` folder. There you could insert your `script` tag in the header section, for example.