# How to add local script file to gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I need add my **local** javascript file to my gatsby project. The file is a library.
What I tried to do:

1) put `myscript.js` to `./src` and import it in `./src/html.js` file as `import from './myscript.js';`

2) put `myscript.js` to `./src` and import it in `./src/html.js` file as `<script type='text/javascript' src="./myscript.js"/>`

3) put `myscript.js` to `./public` and import it in both ways

But none of this works. Please, tell me how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it that you are trying to add? What kind of library? You shouldn't be adding scripts to the Html file (though it is possible) If you want to use an external lib then you install it via npm or yarn and import it in your components.

Check here for adding a custom script to the Html file in a gatsby project: [add script to Html in gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/)

You can also check here which details using different methods for inserting scripts: [more ways to do it](https://www.google.com/amp/s/uxworks.online/how-to-add-a-script-in-head-or-body-tag-in-your-gatsby-website/amp/)

Edit:

You can try using the static folder. Check this answer here:[use static folder gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834930/how-to-include-local-javascript-on-a-gatsby-page)

Comment: it is prebid.js file. It is library for header bidding. It doesn't have any npm modules and every programmer generates his own file

Comment: @Farad so you want to add a script to the site header? You can use React Helmet for that. Or check the links I added to my answer

Comment: thanks, but both of these ways uses src="https://....js", so their js file located somewhere in the Internet. Am I right? But I have this file localy

Comment: one more thing that i tried - to add `<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={...}/>` tag and past there code from my js file. But it doesn't work too

Comment: @Farad ok. You can try using the static folder. Check the link I added above

Comment: I put my file to static folder and just added `<script type="text/javascript" src="prebid3.2.0.js"></script>` to my html.js file. I am not sure but it seems it works, thanks