# Using Gatsby, how can I access variables from an imported JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a JS file that needs to be imported into my gatsby site. This JS file should give me access to a variable called `connect`. Below is a simplified (and working) version of the behavior I am trying to achieve in Gatsby. For simplicity/demonstration it uses only a `index.html` file and a `connect-script.js` file (but still works). Here, I am able to access the `connect` variable as expected:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="connect-script.js"/> // provides access to "connect" variable
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        // some HTML...
        <script>
            console.log(connect) // this IS defined and has expected value from connect-script.js
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, I do not know how to access this `connect` variable from a Gatsby site and use it in my components. I have tried importing the JS file in several ways including using `react-helmet` as well as using a `gatsby-ssr.js` file (both described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066579/including-local-js-and-css-files-using-gatsbyjs?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but errors are always thrown after running `gatsby develop` saying `connect` is not defined.

My component looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import { withPrefix } from 'gatsby'
import Header from './Header'
import Footer from './Footer'

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  console.log(connect) // this is obviously undefined and throws an error.
  return (
    <div>
        <Helmet title='Gatsby'>
          <script src={withPrefix('connect-script.js')}></script>
        </Helmet>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

The JS file is thousands of lines of compiled code, and that is why I am not including code from it. I have tried importing `connect-script.js` with an import statement at the top of the file, but get thousands of errors. I just know that I can access `connect` using a basic setup with one simple `index.html` file and the `connect-script.js` file, but I can not figure out how to access this variable in Gatsby.

If you need to know more about why this is being done in this way, I am trying to incorporate a widget described in [this](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-chat-ui-examples/tree/master/cloudformationTemplates/startChatContactAPI) repo into my gatsby site.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated as I have spent way too many hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

A brilliant developer has helped me with this & I am posting the answer he discovered for any future visitors to this question.

He discovered that I was able to access the `connect` variable in my component by using `window.connect`. I found that this works only when using `gatsby-ssr.js` and NOT when using `Helmet`.

Using gatsby-ssr.js:

```
const React = require("react")

exports.onRenderBody = ({setHeadComponents}) => {
    setHeadComponents([
        <script key='1' type="text/javascript" src={"connect-script.js"}/>
    ]);
};
```

Then in ANY component, I can access the `connect` variable made available by `connect-script.js` by using `window.connect`.

Note: Gatsby uses server side rendering & `window` is not defined during SSR. An option to resolve this would be to wrap your reference to `window` in `componentDidMound` or `useEffect`, for example.

Comment: FWIW, if you try to access `window` during SSR you will end up causing your built to fail.

Comment: @coreyward, definitely worth mentioning, thanks. Answer has been updated.